# Does Safari's history eventually get deleted?

Tags: macos, safari, browser-history

I recently came across a folder in my computer called "History" with over 30 000 (!!) files. It seems that Safari was collecting a copy of every website I visit (probably to display it in the "history" menu...).

[image]

Would this folder keep on growing if I didn't see it and delete its contents?
What is the best way to clean it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your history is cleared automatically per your setting in (Safari) Preferences → General:

[image]

To clear your history manually, go to Safari → Clear History….

[image]